# Django Error While Using PyCharm: "'function' object has no attribute 'using'"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pycharm, static-methods

While working on coding up a REST API using Django and Django REST Framework I all of a sudden got the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1032bc1e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/employees/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import User
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 120, in <module>
    class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 247, in __new__
    opts.field_classes)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 166, in fields_for_model
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1579, in formfield
    'queryset': self.remote_field.model._default_manager.using(db),
  File "/Users/alexarias/PycharmProjects/ContratRestAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset, name)(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'using'
```

I tried uncommenting all the code I had just finished writing and didn't resolve. Checked for odd formatting characters and none... The error appeared almost spontaneously. Code that used to run now doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs when:

1. You've incorrectly defined a method override for a GenericAPIView class
2. PyCharm then suggests to convert method to property
3. You approve and PyCharm converts method to property

Not exactly sure what happens but PyCharm modifies Django package files. Even if you delete the @property decorator the problems remains.
If you catch this immediately (before closing the IDE) then you can ctrl+z to undo the changes and this will resolve the problem.

If you've already closed the IDE or you can't ctrl+z to undo changes then the solution is to uninstall and re-install Django.

Hope this helps! Wrapper issues are tough to debug sometimes!